# Bonsai tree leaves turning brown and falling

Tags: plant-health, leaves, plant-care, bonsai

I have Bonsai tree which it's leaves have been turned brown and falling, even the green leaves are falling.

The tree has been kept inside then moved outside, the issue still appearing.

The below remedies have been tried after noticing the falling of the leaves with no improvement :

1. Change the soil.
2. Increase the humidity with a air humidifier, after leaves felled ( no improvement ).
3. Increase light exposure.
4. Fertilize it with NPK 20 20 20

[image: Bonsai]

[Bonsai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPBfg.jpg)

[image: Leave]

Comment: Did the leaves begin falling off while the tree was still inside, or did they start falling off only after you moved the tree outside. How often do you water it?

Comment: And when did you fertilize - after  the problem started, or before?

Comment: The leaves start falling after I bought the plant directly, it was inside first, then I move it out, but the leaves still fall, I fertilized it after two weeks of the purchase and after noticing the leaves falling.

Comment: If you are in the northern hemisphere, it is spring. This is the normal time for broad leafed evergreens, such as rhododendrons and cork oaks, to drop their old leaves. What is the species of this bonsai?

Comment: I think it's Ficus Microcarpa Ginseng, but it was having alot of green leaves, and it seems like a sudden fall, even if the leave was perfectly green it will fall.